# Remote Path on Deployment Manager, RAD Studio Delphi 10.4 for Windows

Tags: delphi, deployment, path

In the Deployment Manager of RAD Studio Delphi 10.4, how can I indicate the remote path for a file to `c:\ProgramData\MyApplication`?

If I write the path `c:\ProgramData\MyApplication` in the remote path of the Deployment manager, it simply combines this path with that of the program (that is, it tries to install it in `c:\Program Files\MyApplication\C:\ProgramData\MyApplication`).

Comment: I don't think you can use Deployment Manager to deploy some files to some other folders. You will probably have to use dedicated installer for this.

Comment: Thanks, SilverWarior. I'm trying to publish my app in Microsoft Store. They want a msix file.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of MSIX to have whole application stored in one app container? If so then why are you trying to have your application spread across multiple folders?

Comment: Because Microsoft Store install it in Program Files. If I put my database in this folder, my program can't read it, because the system folders are protected.

Comment: Based on [MSIX: how to copy data outside the installation folder during the deployment](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/modern-work-app-consult-blog/msix-how-to-copy-data-outside-the-installation-folder-during-the/ba-p/1133602) you can't deploy your database to external folder directly from MSIX. So you will need to copy your database into `c:\ProgramData\MyApplication` folder on the first start of your application.

Comment: I did not know this page. Thank You very much, SilverWarior

Comment: Yes. Your solution works, SilverWarior. Thank You again.